# Constructing a one-to-one correspondence between given sets.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How should I go about constructing a one-to-one correspondence between sets that are intervals on the set of real numbers? For example, a one-to-one correspondence between (2,4] and [-1,6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea:

- First map $4$ to $-1$
- Now the map$$x \mapsto -1+\frac{7}{2}(x-2)$$ is a bijection form $(2,4)$ to $(-1,6)$

Comment: Or you can use one formula: $x \mapsto -1 - \frac{7}{2}(x-4)$.

Answer (score 0):

I would use $f(x)=-1+\frac{7}{2}(4-x)$

since the first set includes $4$ but excludes $2$, while the second set includes $-1$ but excludes $6$. So, you want to map $4$ to $-1$, and $2$ to $6$ and everything in between in a linear fashion (of course, you don't have $2$ as part of the domain, but you catch my drift)